# Compile and Run Python program in visual studio without the Python extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019 as the text editor to write python program. I want to compile and run the program in the Visual Studio without downloading the VS python extension. I have installed Python 3.8 in the default C://Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38 location.
I do not want to download the extension because the extension installs Python 3.7 on a different location which sometimes become hard to access..

Comment: When you say compile... do you mean debug?

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to make an assumption here that you are relatively new to the Python language. Python isn't "compiled" it's interpreted.

I'm also going to make a recommend (and I should point out that this is purely my own opinion) that you use Visual Studio Code. There is a really good guide for how to get up and running with Python. In general though:

1. Install Python 3.7 from the official [website](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-375/)
2. Install VS Code
3. Open VS Code, install the Python extension
4. Create a new *.py file
5. Select your python version
6. Start editing/debugging